# The nth moment of of normal random variable

Tags: moment-generating-functions

Let $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$. Find $E[X^n]$, where $n \in N$.

What I did was comparing two forms of MGFs, one using the definition of expectation and the other one using taylor series:

$$M_X(s) = e^{\frac{\sigma^2s^2}{2}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\sigma s)^{2n}}{2^nn!}$$

$$M_X(s) = E[e^{sX}] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{s^n}{n!} \cdot E[X^n]$$

Then I equate them:
$\frac{(\sigma s)^{2n}}{2^nn!} = \frac{s^n}{n!}\cdot E[X^n]$, but this gives me $E[X^n] = \Big(\frac{\sigma^2s}{2}\Big)^n$, which does not make sense because it contains the parameter $s$. Where did I do wrong ? Thanks.

Comment: Note that for odd $n$, $E(X^n)=0$. For even $n$, try to find a recurrence on $n$.

Comment: how do you get $E(X^n) = 0$ for odd $n$, what do I do with the extra parameter $s$?

Comment: $X^n$ is symmetric. Using the [LOTUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) the integral trivially vanishes (which is by the way the method I would use to derive the recurrence, but if you know the MGF you just have to expand in power series).

Comment: Is my method above correct though?

Comment: I don't see how my method would give $E(X^n) = 0$ for odd $n$.

Comment: Your method is correct, but you didn't pay enough attention. There is a $s^{2n}$ in one expression and $s^n$ in the other. You must equate coefficients of same monomial.

Comment: How would I equate them?

Comment: Sorry, I am still not understanding your statement, do you mind providing more details? Would really appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: If $a_0+a_2s^2+a_4s^4=b_0+b_1s+b_2s^2+b_3s^3+b_4s^4$, then $b_0=a_0, b_1=0,b_2=a_2,\dots$

Answer (score 1):

The $n^\textrm{th}$ moment is the $n^\textrm{th}$ derivative of $M_X(s)$ evaluated at $s=0$.

$$m_n = \left. \frac{d^n M_X(s)}{ds}\right|_{s=0}$$

For example, for the Gaussian centered at zero that you indicate,

$$m_1 =\left. s\sigma^2 e^{\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 s^2}\right|_{s=0} =0$$ and $$m_2= \left. (s^2 \sigma^4 + \sigma^2)e^{\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 s^2}\right|_{s=0} = \sigma^2.$$

$$\underline{\textbf{UPDATE, based on your question below:}}$$

$${}{}{}$$

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}m_k \cdot \frac{s^k}{k!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\sigma s)^{2n}}{2^nn!} $$

If $k$ odd, $m_k=0$.

If $k$ even, $k=2n$ and

$$m_k = \frac{\sigma^k k!}{ 2^{k/2} (k/2)!}$$

which allows us to write

$$\begin{aligned} 
m_1&=0\\
m_2&=\sigma^2\\
m_3&=0\\
m_4&= \frac{4! \sigma^4}{4 \cdot 2!}=3\sigma^4\\
m_5&=0\\
&\textit{etc.}
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: I'm trying to derive the formula for the nth moment without using derivatives. Could you point out any mistakes I made in my work?

Comment: See @Jean-Claude Arbaut's comment.  Equating them shows that for $n$ odd, the $n^\textrm{th}$ moment is zero.  Now equate the even moments.

Comment: @Anonymous, updated to show this method.